# Rich Faces 4.2.2.Final Cannot get skin to work

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Im new to RichFaces. For my application, I cant apply the skin to my datatable component. I know there are existing thread regarding this https://community.jboss.org/thread/161480  I followed all the configurations but the skin still wont applied. See image below.

[image]

I tried the 4.0.0.20101226-M5 version as mention in the thread but it still wont work. Here's my current code:

My pom.xml

```html
 <properties>
     <org.richfaces.bom.version>4.2.2.Final</org.richfaces.bom.version>
     <webflow-version>2.3.1.RELEASE</webflow-version>
     <mojarra-version>2.1.7</mojarra-version>
 </properties>

  <!-- RichFaces -->

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.cdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>         
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
       <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

My web.xml

```html
  <!-- Use JSF view templates saved as *.xhtml, for use with Facelets -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
      <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <!-- Enables special Facelets debug output during development -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Causes Facelets to refresh templates during development -->
   <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <!-- Plugging the "Blue Sky" skin into the project -->
   <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-    
    class>
   </listener>
    <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <!-- change servlet-context.xml to web-application-config.xml -->
  <param-value><!-- /WEB-INF/spring/web-application-config.xml --></param-value>
   </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize, *not* used at runtime -->
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My page

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
         xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
         xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<h:head>
     <title>Data Tables</title>
</h:head> 

<h:body>
     <h3>JSF STARTED!</h3>
<rich:panel>

     <rich:dataTable value="#{userBean.users}" var="user" rows="5" >
<rich:column>
     <f:facet name="header">User</f:facet>
     <h:outputText id="name" value="#{user.name}"/>
</rich:column>
<rich:column>
     <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
     <h:outputText id="email" value="#{user.email}"/>
</rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>

</rich:panel>

</h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Sorry for the wall of text but any advise given will be appreciated!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you describe in web developer's perspective what exactly failed instead of in enduser's perspective. Or are you also completely new to web development in general? (i.e. you are not familiar with basic HTTP and HTML at all?) To start, view the JSF-generated HTML source and check if CSS references are all right and press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug and check if the HTTP traffic is all right.

Comment: I do know the basic of http and html but for Spring MVC and RichFaces, its my first time trying. I followed your suggestion and manage to find out the error " Fail to GET skinning.ecss "

Answer (score 4):

Try starting your facelet with a `<html>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
        <h:head>
        ...
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
         ...
        </h:body>
</html>
```

See if that helps.